# Deserialise JSON array including type info

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I am tyring to deserialise a JSON array using Jackson were the first element is a type ID, then there are some other elements, and finially the payload which will be of a type specified by the first element. It seems to fail trying to resolve the type

I have made a simplifed runnable example here

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

class Scratch {

    private static  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({"type", "uniqueId", "animal"})
    public static class Wrapper {

        public String type;
        public String uniqueId;

        @JsonTypeInfo(
                use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
                include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
                property = "type"
        )
        @JsonSubTypes({
                @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")
        })
        public Animal animal;
    }

    public interface Animal {
        int getLegs();
    }

    public static class Cat implements Animal {

        public int legs = 4;
        @Override
        public int getLegs() {
            return legs;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
        wrapper.type = "cat";
        wrapper.uniqueId = "123";
        wrapper.animal = new Cat();

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
        System.out.println(json);

        Wrapper deserialized = objectMapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
        System.out.println(deserialized);
    }
}
```

It can correctly serialize to

```
["cat","123",{"legs":4}]
```

But when attempting deserialization an exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `Scratch$Wrapper` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"["cat","123",{"legs":4}]"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1415)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanAsArrayDeserializer._deserializeNonVanilla(BeanAsArrayDeserializer.java:226)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanAsArrayDeserializer.deserialize(BeanAsArrayDeserializer.java:108)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3597)
    at Scratch.main(scratch_86.java:51)
```

If the type of field in the `Wrapper` is changed from `Animal` to `Cat` and the `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` removed it can deserialize ok. So this makes me think the issue is in the sub type resolving but not sure what is wrong, any ideas?

Comment: *"an exception is thrown"*  Mind to share *what* exception?

Comment: Added exception

Comment: In discussion here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/4277

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue, you shuold change `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` to `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` or `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ANY)` or you can also remove it.

Output

```
{"type":"cat","uniqueId":"123","animal":{"legs":4}}
Scratch.Wrapper(type=cat, uniqueId=123, animal=Scratch.Cat(legs=4))
```

Comment: This is not really a fix. It will work in my example but that's because i'm serializing first as demo code. In the real case I cannot control the serialized form and it mush be JSON array